# Error Downloading MariaDB Server on MacOS 10.15 no-system-libs

Tags: cmake, mariadb, homebrew, macos-catalina

I've been trying to install a MariaDB server on to my macOS via homebrew and the program seems to stop on a line

`./bootstrap --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.28.3 --no-system-libs --paral`

I've tried to install the binary distribution for 3.28.3 but it seems to disappear every time I terminate the window since there's no progress being made on fetching more dependencies.

I've made more progress with trying to get ahead of the program  using

`$brew install cmake jemalloc traildb/judy/judy openssl boost gnutls`

vs

`$brew install mariadb`

but it usually gets stuck after installing mariadb dependency: cmake and doesn't make it to the other dependencies. Oddly enough it doesn't end in an error message, just the ./bootstrap line above

but I'm not entirely sure where to go from here. I imagine theres possibility of homebrew not supporting the macOS 10.15 OS Intel i5